# Заполнить массив свойств (настроек)

Tags: c#, массивы, wpf

```
Array[] a = new Array[30];
        Properties.CostPrice.Default.Properties.CopyTo(a,0);
```

Пишет что невозможно скопировать в массив данного типа, как узнать какого типа должен быть массив ? 
тип свойств long.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо Array указать long?

Comment: Изначально так и пробовал, не получилось, я думаю там структура должна быть

Comment: Что у Вас хранится в Properties? Массив элементов типа long?

Comment: @DanBear Поля типа лонг с именем и значением

Comment: Можете добавить пример в вопрос? А то я не могу понять, там массив или просто набор переменных long.

Comment: @DanBear да, добавил

Comment: То есть, у Вас там переменные "babyL", "choccolateL", "cacaoS" и т.д? Тогда не получиться сделать это через CopyTo. Этот метод копирует массив в другой, а у Вас массива нет. Единственный способ (который мне приходит в голову) это инициализировать массив со всеми этими переменными вручную или можете заменить переменные на словарь и потом получить все значения словаря в массив.

Comment: @DanBear Спасибо что уделили время моему вопросу, я так и думал изначально сделать, но хотелось минимизировать строчки кода)